# Verificar si hay acceso a Internet Android Studio

Tags: android

estoy enviando datos desde **Android Studio** a **Mysql** mediante archivos **PHP**.
mi problema es que no siempre habra *Internet*, he probado varios metodos que lo unico que hacen es verificar si hay internet, todo bien hasta alli. mi problema empieza cuando esta conectado a una Red Wifi pero no hay acceso a internet. ¿Como puedo saber si hay acceso a internet, es decir, no solo verificar que este conectado a una red, si no que realmente haya?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean conectadoAInternet() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    String comando = "ping -c 1 facebook.com";
    return (Runtime.getRuntime().exec (comando).waitFor() == 0);
}
```

Haz ping a facebook o google y si recibes respuesta es que tienes internet

Comment: *Ejecutar un proceso en Android para realizar un ping a la página web y comprobar conectividad no creo que sea buena práctica....* para eso es la clase **NetworkInfo** !

Comment: utilizo `networkinfo` y no me funciona